# Why does a soft keyboard automatically appear on clearFocus()?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am calling clearFocus on the edit text when the user clicks the done button. However, when I do this the app gains focus on the container and a keyboard appears. When I add a dummy View, it gains focus on that view but a keyboard still appears! This keyboard doesn't do anything as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can force Android to hide the virtual keyboard using the **InputMethodManager**, calling **hideSoftInputFromWindow**, passing in the token of the window containing your focused view.

```
// Check if no view has focus:
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

This will force the keyboard to be hidden in all situations. In some cases you will want to pass in InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY as the second parameter to ensure you only hide the keyboard when the user didn't explicitly force it to appear (by holding down menu).

Note: If you want to do this in Kotlin, use:

`context?.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager`

See more answers on this thread [Hide Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)